# The usage of "it"

Tags: pronouns

I don't understand what regulates the usage of IT in the following sentences. My statement is based on opinions of natives. For example, they say:

> 1) What day is it today? - OK
>
> 2) Today, it is Monday. - wrong (should be - It is Monday, today.)

I think people consider TODAY a noun, if so, then we really have "NOUN + IT" which is wrong. But TODAY can be an adverbial modifier of time.

> 3) Today is Tom's birthday - OK
>
> 4) Whose birthday is today? wrong (should be - Whose birthday is it today?)

If 3 is correct, why is 4 wrong?

> 5) Today it is cold. - OK
>
> 6) Today it is Sunday. - wrong

Any reliable explanation?

Comment: Are you saying that these unnamed natives are saying your sentences are wrong? *Today, it is Monday* is fine. In fact, the corrected version is wrong. If you reverse the elements, there should be no comma. (*It is Monday today*) Several other claims are also incorrect.

Comment: I posted firsthand info which I got in the form of opinions of natives'. I can't evaluate their knowledge, so I write what I hear from them. This site is for simple questions from learners of English. I think my question qualifies for it. If you can, please, go ahead and explain to me what is correct and what is not correct.

Comment: Have you read about the [**dummy it**?](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/dummy-subjects)  That may help you understand the sentences better.

Comment: How does it explain 3 and 4?

Answer (score 1):

> 2) Today, it is Monday.

This is correct, the adverb "today" can be placed at the start or the end of the sentence. Placing time adverbs at the end may be more common; adverb placement is a complex subject, but there is usually some flexibility in how adverbs are placed.

Both "Today is Tom's birthday" and "Today, it is Tom's birthday" are correct. Today can function as a noun and as an adverb.  You could also place "today" at the end. Similarly "Whose birthday is today?" and "Whose Birthday is it today" are acceptable, though the second sounds better. Perhaps this is because "today" is optional, in context. You can just say "Whose birthday is it?"

"Today, it is Sunday" is acceptable as is "Today is Sunday".